# Ayuda Inner Join Mysql

Tags: mysql

Bueno pasa lo siguientes trato de hacer un inner join a 2 tablas por medio de su llave foranea pero devuelve vacio y hay 2 registros

en serviteca_clientes tengo la llave primaria llamada cli_identificacion
y en serviteca_ventas tengo cli_identificacionque es la foranea

Bueno para agregar su llave foranea use la siguiente sentencia

ALTER TABLE serviteca_ventas ADD CONSTRAINT CliVen FOREIGN KEY (cli_identificacion) REFERENCES serviteca_clientes(cli_identificacion)
ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE;

SELECT c.cli_identificacion, c.cli_nombre
FROM serviteca_ventas AS b
INNER JOIN serviteca_clientes AS c
ON (c.`cli_identificacion` = b.`cli_identificacion`)
WHERE c.`cli_identificacion` = b.`cli_identificacion`

pero devuelve vacio y en serviteca_clientes hay 2 registros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¿Estás seguro que en la tabla  **serviteca_ventas** hay ventas asociadas a esos clientes? Eso es lo primero a tomar en cuenta. Pero el problema está en la siguiente línea:

```
WHERE c.cli_identificacion = b.cli_identificacion
```

Con solo quitar dicha sentencia te debería traer los registros que existen en la tabla **serviteca_ventas**. Debería ser:

```
 SELECT campos_selecionados FROM serviteca_ventas AS b 
 INNER JOIN serviteca_clientes AS c ON b.cli_identificacion=c.cli_identificacion
```

Cuando haces un join y enlazas los campos correspondientes equivaldría al where que pones. Pero dado el caso no necesitas esto al menos que desees filtrar por alguna identificación de cliente. Por ejemplo:

```
 SELECT campos_selecionados FROM serviteca_ventas AS b 
 INNER JOIN serviteca_clientes AS c ON b.cli_identificacion=c.cli_identificacion WHERE b.cli_identificacion = '123456789'
```

Comment: Los trae vacios lo puse tal y como me dijiste arriba sin usar WHERE

Comment: Pero hay datos en la tabla de ventas enlazada a los clientes que tienes creados?

Comment: Amigo efectivamente puse una venta y si aparecio muchas gracias