# Relacionar en un select un id con su valor referido en otra tabla MariaDB

Tags: mysql, sql, select, mariadb

tengo dos tablas de MariaDB similares al siguiente ejemplo:

Tabla 1, servicios:

| direccion | id_empresa |
| --- | --- |
| dirección 1 | 1 |
| dirección 2 | 2 |

Tabla 2, empresas:

| id_empresa | nombre |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Empresa 1 |
| 2 | Empresa 2 |

Necesito hacer una select de la tabla 1 (servicios) que me muestre los datos pero en vez de decirme el id de la empresa me diga el nombre del siguiente modo:

- dirección 1, empresa 1
- dirección 2, empresa 2

Lo he conseguido con la siguiente query, pero creo que no es la manera más eficiente y quería preguntar si hay alguna solución mejor.

```
SELECT t1.direccion, 
(SELECT nombre FROM empresas t2 WHERE t1.id_empresa = t2.id_empresa LIMIT 1) AS empresa
FROM servicios t1
```

¡Muchas gracias por la posible ayuda

Comment: Debes utilizar inner join para crear la relacion https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/214683/ayuda-inner-join-mysql

Answer (score 1):

Lo que necesitas es utilizar un JOIN para relacionar ambas tablas, quedaría de esta forma:

```
SELECT t1.direccion,t2.nombre
FROM servicios t1 
INNER JOIN empresas AS t2 ON t2.id_empresa = t1.id_empresa
```

Utilicé INNER JOIN, pero, de acuerdo a tus necesidades, te aconsejo que investigues sobre los diferentes 'JOIN' que puedes utilizar, saludos.